# How to get code coverage numbers accurate with isparta, webpack, jasmine and karma?

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, ecmascript-6, jasmine, isparta

I am having difficulty getting the correct code coverage numbers when trying to use a combination of webpack, isparta, jasmine and karma. The numbers at the end of a test run do not reflect the ES6 code correctly. However, the UI shows the correct ES6 file, with the correct highlighting, just not the correct numbers.

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about.

Wrong Code Coverage Numbers:

[image: Wrong Code Coverage Numbers]

The code and highlighting is correct, but the numbers are not. For example, the Statement number is completely off. I am assuming these numbers are coming from the transpiled code.

Here is my karma.config.js:

```
'use strict';

var conf = require('./gulp/conf');
var _ = require('lodash');
var wiredep = require('wiredep');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

function listFiles() {
    var wiredepOptions = _.extend({}, conf.wiredep, {
        dependencies: true,
        devDependencies: true
    });

    var dependencies = wiredep(wiredepOptions).js;

    dependencies.push('test-context.js');

    return dependencies;
}

module.exports = function(config) {

    var configuration = {
        files: listFiles(),
        logLevel: 'WARN',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        browsers : ['PhantomJS'],
        plugins : [
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-webpack'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'test-context.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: webpackConfig,
        webpackMiddleware: {
            noInfo: true
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
        coverageReporter: {
            dir : 'coverage/',
            reporters: [
                { type: 'html' }
            ]
        }
    };

    config.set(configuration);
};
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    node: {
      fs: 'emtpy'
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'isparta',
                include: /(src)/
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: /(src)/,
                loader: 'babel?stage=0'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '',
            '.js'
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

Here is the test.context.js:

```
var context = require.context('./test', true, /\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);

var srcContext = require.context('./src', true, /\.js$/);
srcContext.keys().forEach(srcContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GitHub account you can see this [list of real projects which use webpack with isparta, jasmine, and karma](https://github.com/search?l=JSON&q=webpack+isparta+jasmine+karma&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for a set of working examples to compare against. Hope this helps, thanks.